# Ubuntu Image installed on USB, Cannot use remaining space

Tags: partitioning, usb

I installed an Ubuntu Live CD (15.04 Desktop) image on a 16gb Flash Drive and am working from it, leaving 14 GB (14,461,632,512 bytes) remaining. I try to make a partition using the rest from "Disks", and I get this message:

```
Error creating partition on /dev/sdb: Command-line `parted --align optimal --script "/dev/sdb" "mkpart primary ext2 1100MiB 15614803967b"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
(udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Here are the statistics:

```
Partition Size: 14462 mb
Free Space Following: 0 mb
Partition Type: FAT32
Erase Method: Quick
Partition Name: "Justadoo444"
Model: Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 (PMAP)
```

Partitions Included:

1.

```
"Ubuntu 15.04 amd64" (1.2 gb (1,150,844,928 bytes))
Contents: ISO 9660 (version Joliet Extension)
Type: 0x00 (Bootable)
```

2.

```
"Ubuntu 15.04 amd64" (2.3 MB (2,326,528 bytes))
Contents: FAT (12-bit version)
Type: EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

Comment: what method did you use to get the image on the device? did you use dd or cat or something?